# GCD slow updating UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Im using GCD to download a plist file from the internet then enter the data into an array then load it into a tableView.

The data is being downloaded and converted alright but the table view is taking ages to update. I have the app Logging something when it calls [self.tableView reloadData] but the table view updates about 10 seconds later.

I don't think this is about the table view because I tried changing the title of the Navigation Bar inside the GCD and there was also a delay. So it might be a delay updating the user interface?

This is my GCD code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
```

Thanks for you help

EDIT:

This is my code:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
 UERootArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url to file"]];

NSLog(@"Array: %@", UERootArray);
//NSLog(@"count %@",count);

NSString *currentName;
NSString *currentLoaction;
NSString *currentDate;

int currentEventInt = 0;

NSArray *currentEventArr = [UERootArray objectAtIndex:0];

while (currentEventArr.count > currentEventInt)
{
    currentName = [currentEventArr objectAtIndex:0];
    currentLoaction = [currentEventArr objectAtIndex:1];
    currentDate = @"7pm 17/11"; //[currentEventArr objectAtIndex:2];

    NSLog (@"Title: %@", currentName);
    NSLog (@"News: %@", currentLoaction);
    NSLog (@"Date: %@", currentDate);

    UEEvent *currentTask = [[UEEvent alloc] initWithName:currentName location:currentLoaction date:currentDate];
    [self.upcommingEvents addObject:currentTask];

    currentEventInt = currentEventInt + 1;
}
UEDownloaded = YES;

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Edit 2:

```
- (void)downloadUEData
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    UERootArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url to file"]];
        [self processUEData];
    });
}

- (void)processUEData
{
    NSLog(@"Array: %@", UERootArray);
    //NSLog(@"count %@",count);

    NSString *currentName;
    NSString *currentLoaction;
    NSString *currentDate;

    int currentEventInt = 0;

    NSArray *currentEventArr = [UERootArray objectAtIndex:0];

    while (currentEventArr.count > currentEventInt)
    {
        currentName = [currentEventArr objectAtIndex:0];
        currentLoaction = [currentEventArr objectAtIndex:1];
        currentDate = @"7pm 17/11"; //[currentEventArr objectAtIndex:2];

        NSLog (@"Title: %@", currentName);
        NSLog (@"News: %@", currentLoaction);
        NSLog (@"Date: %@", currentDate);

        UEEvent *currentTask = [[UEEvent alloc] initWithName:currentName location:currentLoaction date:currentDate];
        [self.upcommingEvents addObject:currentTask];

        currentEventInt = currentEventInt + 1;
    }
    UEDownloaded = YES;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: UI updates must be done on the main thread, not a background thread.

Comment: Can you share a bit more of the code?

Comment: @maddy so if I add a method to be run after the download and put the UI updates in there?

Comment: Then that would be the main thread and the correct way of doing it. Anything run under the GCD is on a background thread. That's not the place for UI updates.

Comment: Ok I changed the code and put data processing into its own method but it still has a delay? @Tander

Comment: You need to wrap the reloadData call in another GCD block, but dispatching to the MAIN queue

Comment: I have updated my code to what I have done... @itsthejb

Comment: @itsthejb How do I do that, sorry I'm kind of confused?

Comment: Just wrap [self.tableView reloadData] in its own GCD block dispatching to dispatch_get_main_queue. This pattern of main queue -> dispatch background -> dispatch back to main for UI update is very common

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new to GCD, could you possibly send the code? Its ok if you can't. @itsthejb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think following code will solve your problem ...

```
- (void)downloadUEData
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    UERootArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.nytrex.webs.com/Linx/upcommingEvents.plist"]];
        [self processUEData];
    });
}

- (void)processUEData
{
    NSLog(@"Array: %@", UERootArray);
    //NSLog(@"count %@",count);

    NSString *currentName;
    NSString *currentLoaction;
    NSString *currentDate;

    int currentEventInt = 0;

    NSArray *currentEventArr = [UERootArray objectAtIndex:0];

    while (currentEventArr.count > currentEventInt)
    {
        currentName = [currentEventArr objectAtIndex:0];
        currentLoaction = [currentEventArr objectAtIndex:1];
        currentDate = @"7pm 17/11"; //[currentEventArr objectAtIndex:2];

        NSLog (@"Title: %@", currentName);
        NSLog (@"News: %@", currentLoaction);
        NSLog (@"Date: %@", currentDate);

        UEEvent *currentTask = [[UEEvent alloc] initWithName:currentName location:currentLoaction date:currentDate];
        [self.upcommingEvents addObject:currentTask];

        currentEventInt = currentEventInt + 1;
    }
    UEDownloaded = YES;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{   // update your UI in main thread

       [self.tableView reloadData];         

   });
}
```